# HTML+CSS Template: Query Lists

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to develop some templates for common `HTML` + `CSS` tasks I've been dealing with. One of which is a general 'query list' (??) either from client- or server-side.
So far I'm using the following reusable code which seems to be working fine without any noticeable bug:

```css
/* Query List */

ul.query-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  min-width: 340px;
}

ul.query-list li {
  height: 5.7em;
  margin: 10px 0;
  font-size: 12px;
}

ul.query-list li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}

ul.query-list li a:hover {
  background-color: #fafafa;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

ul.query-list li a:hover .title-container {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

ul.query-list .image-container {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 5.7em;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

ul.query-list .text-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

ul.query-list .title-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 0.2em;
}

ul.query-list .title-container .no-title {
  color: darkgray;
  font-weight: bold;
}

ul.query-list .notes-container {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-grow: 0;
  height: 1.1em;
  overflow: hidden;
}

ul.query-list .notes-container p {
  color: darkgray;
  text-align: left;
}

.query-list p,
h3 {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1.1em;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: arial;
}

.query-list span {
  white-space: nowrap
}


/* General Definitions */

.icon-img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  display: block;
}

h3 {
  color: darkblue;
}
```

```html
<ul class="query-list">
  <li>
    <a href="dummy_page1.html">
      <div class="image-container">
        <img class="icon-img" src="img_100x100.png">
      </div>

      <div class="text-container">
        <div class="title-container">
          <h3 title="dummy title">[Dummy Title] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse quis accumsan felis. Maecenas vel libero mi. Suspendisse potenti. Sed tempus ex eu diam imperdiet mattis ac ut orci. Sed non lectus libero. Suspendisse vitae
            nunc a quam mattis congue id eget tortor. Vivamus id arcu eros. Duis eu risus semper, dapibus quam in, tristique magna. Duis semper tempus dolor eget elementum. Duis arcu ipsum, suscipit a egestas quis, lobortis sit amet purus.</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="notes-container">
          <p>
            <span>dummy notes 1</span>
            <span>&bull; dummy notes 2</span>
            <span>&bull; dummy notes 3</span>
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="notes-container">
          <p>
            <span>dummy notes 4</span>
            <span>&bull; dummy notes 5</span>
            <span>&bull; dummy notes 6</span>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Some main characteristics of this code are:

- the text content has a maximum of 5 lines (title + notes) independently of the amount of text content
- independently of the number of title lines, the notes are always immediately bellow (no variable gap)
- the maximum number of title lines automatically adjust according to the number of notes lines included or removed

**Issue**

1. There is a nest of `<div>`, `<a>` and `flexbox` that seems to me overly complicated for such a simple task. Is it possible to simplify it?
2. Is there a standard nomenclature for this issue? 'Query-list' seems somewhat confusing.

Comment: you could just use a `grid` if the nesting is bothering you...

Comment: @Anthony First time I've heard of this feature. However, at first glance, seems to be the way to go. Very helpful advice. Thnk!

Comment: no problemoooo!

Comment: @Anthony I'm extremely amazed by `grid`. It could be very helpful not only for this simple 'query-list', but also for the whole page structures (including media queries). I still need to dig deeper into it, therefore would you mind to anticipate for me some hints? Ex: 1) cross-browser and -platform compatible? 2) smartphone friendly? 3) Known bugs?

Comment: @Anthony ["An important thing to understand about Grid is that it's not ready to be used in production yet."](http://chris.house/blog/a-complete-guide-css-grid-layout/)

Comment: you do realize the link you provided is from **March 4, 2016?** https://caniuse.com/#search=grid

Comment: @Anthony _"you do realize the link you provided is from March 4, 2016?"_ Yes, I'm aware of. So far was the only link I've found discussing this issue.

Comment: try google. info about it is literally everywhere nowadays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are referring to are search results (query-list). You can definitely simplify your notes section by adding it to an unordered list and using CSS to break it into columns for you. You also don't need to wrap the whole structure into a list, you could just use a wrapper div.

Example of an unordered list in columns:

```
<div class="notes-container">
  <ul>
    <li>dummy notes 1</li>
    <li>dummy notes 2</li>
    <li>dummy notes 3</li>
    <li>dummy notes 4</li>
    <li>dummy notes 5</li>
    <li>dummy notes 6</li>
  </ul>
</div>

ul {
  -moz-column-count: 5;
  -moz-column-gap: 5px;
  -webkit-column-count: 5;
  -webkit-column-gap: 5px;
  column-count: 5;
  column-gap: 5px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/smulvihill/e8y9joLb/29/) with simplified structure and CSS.

Comment: _"You also don't need to wrap the whole structure into a list"_ Consider the most common case for this 'query-list', ie, client full-text search. Take a look at the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b8w5syrh/1/). Would you still recommend to avoid wrapping the whole structure into a list?

Comment: _"[...] using CSS to break it into columns for you."_ Very helpful indeed. Never seen `column-count` before. I'm gonna read more about it. Mind to explain if this command is cross-browsers and -platforms compatible?

Comment: I have done many search implementations and have never wrapped results in an unordered list, find it's easier to work with divs instead, especially with more complex layouts with multiple columns.

Comment: _"find it's easier to work with divs instead"_ Ok, I agree there are some advantages using `<div>` instead of `<ul>` (ex: no need for `list-style-type: none;`). However, there is an issue of semantics here: `<div>` tags are very broad and can be used almost everywhere (`<section>`, `<article>`, `<footer>`, `<nav>`, `<header>`, ...). Sometimes is good to indicate in your code what you have (for example, a list of results).

Comment: If you are interested in semantics, wrap your results in article tags: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/sections.html#the-article-element

Comment: _"wrap your results in article tags"_ Agree, usually there is an article tag wrapping some heading tag + list tag + pagination div tag.